# Learning Peano's notation

Tags: logic, bertrand-russell

This is more a request than a question.
I would like to read Russell's *The Logic of Relations* in which he uses Peano's notation. I'm looking for a text available online which would explain thoroughly the notation, at least for the purpose of reading Russell's essay.
Thank you in advance.

(Just in case: The SEP entry on the notation of *PM* is clearly insufficient in this regard)

Comment: For some examples, see the post : [What did Whitehead and Russell's “Principia Mathematica” achieve ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597819/what-did-whitehead-and-russells-principia-mathematica-achieve)

Answer (score 1):

For Peano, see : [G.Peano, *Arithmetices principia* (1889)](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) with : Hubert Kennedy (editor), [Selected works of Giuseppe Peano](https://books.google.it/books?id=6upLAAAAMAAJ) and Jean Van Heijenoort (editor), [From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879-1931](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA83), page 83-on, for English translations.

For *Principia*, you can see [Glossary of Principia Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Principia_Mathematica) as well as W&R, [Principia Mathematica to *56](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA4).

Also useful : Evgeny A. Zaitsev, [An interpretation of Peano's logic](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00375641) (1993).